# How I can get the result of a price in web-scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, data-analysis

I am trying to do a simple bot of web-scraping on Python to show my girlfriend when her favorite sneakers get on sale, I have seen many videos and tried a lot of things, the Title and other information about the sneaker is working, but the always results as `None`, I have also tried in other websites and get the same result.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.vans.com.br/tenis-ultrarange-rapidweld-black-white/p/1003500430051U?gad_source=1"
headers = {'User-Agent': "insera aqui seu User Agent"} ## retirei meu user agent mas só pra nao postar com ele

site = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find('h1', class_= 'product-name').get_text()
price = soup.find('div', class_='ta-product-price__total' or 'product-price')

print(title)
print(price)
```

[image]

I have tried getting the price with many different things in the variable price, switch `div` to `span` and other things, but none was succeed, also tried the same thing with other websites and get the same result.

Comment: The page has dynamically content (JavaScript) that's why you cannot access like that. Using your browser you can right-click to source code of the page, copy it locally in your PC and make some attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see is loaded from external URL via JavaScript. You can try instead:

```py
import requests

number = "1003500430051U"

url = f"https://www.vans.com.br/arezzocoocc/v2/vans/products/{number}/dynamic-product-fields?fields=DYNAMIC_FIELDS_PDP"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0"
}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

for c in data["colorOptions"]:
    if c["code"] == number:
        print(c["name"], data["price"]["value"])
        break
```

Prints:

```
Tênis Ultrarange Rapidweld Black White 549.99
```